# android service running on a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

I have an application that starts on boot using a broadcast receiver, also I have an activity and a process, because the service must run always on the background I am starting the service on it's own process using the android:process manifest tag.

The ui is only for presentational needs and I would like the user to be able to run the service even if the activity is not active.

I am starting the service using this extra parameter:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_DONT_KILL_APP, true);
```

the problem is that when I press the back button or the home button the activity's on destroy method is called and the service although seems its running (it appears on the task manager) its not behaving as supposed, it should connect to the net and send some data but every X time using an timer task but the task never fires so the data are never send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because the service must run always on the background

Please don't do that. For starters, it is impossible, since Android will kill you off, and users will kill you off. Considering how much RAM you are wasting with your current implementation, both will attempt to kill you off much more quickly.

> I am starting the service on it's own process using the android:process manifest tag.

Please don't do that either. You are wasting RAM to no benefit. You do not need a separate process for this service.

> I am starting the service using this extra parameter:

That parameter does not do what you think it does. It is not used with starting services.

> it should connect to the net and send some data but every X time using an timer task but the task never fires so the data are never send.

Step #1: Get rid of your existing service.

Step #2: Use `AlarmManager` and a [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). Schedule an alarm (perhaps using your boot-time receiver) to be invoked "every X time". Have the `WakefulIntentService` "connect to the net and send some data".

Comment: thanks for the advice,but 1 I am using about 3 mb of ram wich is little compaired to any other service running on the phone,2 what it's used for (the extra parameter)? 3 why not use a seperate process? when should I? 4 I am aware about the alarm manager but I want my updates at certain periods which alarm manager can't guarantee.

Comment: @maxasp: 1. Android won't care. Users won't care. 2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_DONT_KILL_APP 3. Because you waste twice the RAM, for no benefit. 4. `AlarmManager` works perfectly fine, thank you. If you have proof to the contrary, post it.

Comment: The actual application is the service the activity is only for the first time the program runs, so why use double RAM? please explain, android will reclaim the memory used by the activity's process (correct me if I am wrong). I have already read that reference that's why I used it when is says "override the default action of restarting the application" doesn't that incled the services? Didn't know about the setRepeating method sorry, but can I change the interval dynamically? in the current form the service gets notified about new interval and sets up the timer task.

Comment: Then don't use setRepeating, but just schedule a new alarm.  Just like you are doing with timers.  But use alarms.

Comment: other than the separate process is there any reason for the service stops when the user is killing the activity?

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with CommonsWare's answer. But, if you really want to bother users with yet-another-useless-service-which-sits-in-the-background-just-eating-memory you could use the following:

In your activity:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, UpdateService.class);
serviceIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

In your service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null) {
        .. do something here
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Again, please DO NOT do this just to execute some action periodically. PLEASE use the AlarmManager!